# Ways to protect my framework in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

We intend to sell our framework on the net ,and it needs to be protected in a matter than if someone buying it, he can't put it on the net, or give it to other developers .
We dont want to find it all over the net after a few months.

I had a few ways in mind but each had its catch .

Give a unique ID to every developer, and program that id to the framework, so he must enter that to use it. problem is ,that he can give the framework with the id to anyone .

Ask for the device number and enable only that device in my framework for each developer. problem here is that when he put it on store, all users cant use that since they have others device id.

Use the net to check some how(??) which i preferred not to limit the users to that need.

I can program each framework with a code, that only me can extract, so when i find it on the net i can be sure what dev put it in there (it doesn't help-i cant sue everyone)

Is there any other way to make the framework per developer but also let it work on all other users at the appstore when its there ?

Thanks .

Comment: What if, instead of giving each customer a unique ID, you ask them for their company identifier (com.yourcompanyname.*) and bury that into your code. Then, make your code work only if the host app's bundleID matches the pattern. Now they can give the framework to anyone, but the other party is forced to use your customer's reverse domain (huge annoyance?).

Comment: This is a very interesting way ! i will have to check that ,to see if we dont miss something . thanks a lot .

Answer (score 3):

@diederikh makes very good points, and NicolasMiari also provides good insight. The best answer IMO is a combination of these two. (While keeping in mind diederikh's excellent advice that your goal is to come up with something simple that will make things hard on legitimate customers.)

Rather than recompiling your entire framework for every customer, you make your license key depend on their bundle identifier. They send you their bundle ID. You use your private key and sign their bundle id. This provides you a hash that you send to them. Now, at runtime, your framework uses the public key (which is not sensitive; you could publish it anywhere) to verify your signature. See `SecKeyRawVerify()` for doing that on iOS.

You can use this approach to create time-limited keys. Just include time stamps in the signed data.

Using this approach, you could, if you wanted, let customers test your framework indefinitely by using *your* bundle identifier. You would make a signed hash of that identifier available to trial customers. But as soon as they want to upload to AppStore, they would have to change the identifier and pay you for a new signed key.

There certainly is a way to get around this. Attackers could modify your framework to ignore the signature verification. But that's always true, and preventing that is better done with lawyers after the fact than with DRM that will only likely cause trouble for paying customers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how PSPDFKit does it. If you want to use it out of demo mode you'll have to call a method with an unique ID. This ID will enable functionality which is not available in demo mode.

You can also sign (with the codesign tool) the framework with an unique certificate for each customer.

I would not worry too much; if will always find a way around your locks.

Comment: But if they have to call a method with a unique id, so i have to give to someone that unique id , so he can just give that to the rest of the world- which was exactly what i wrote in my question .. so i dont understand ..

Comment: I am not sure how PSPDFKit does it but maybe it checks the code on the server. You can then blacklist codes that are distributed on the internet. You'll never find a 100% (or even 90%) solution that will not annoy your customers.